# Shared Outlook Color Categories Appearing for other users after deletion

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a shared mb that was setup by IT, accessing via O:365.  I'm listed as the owner and have used the Manage Categories function to delete all the default color categories and add 4 custom color and named categories for events in the shared calendar.

When I select the Categories flyout menu its just the 4 custom.  When other users who have been shared permission go to edit an events Category, they see my custom categories, plus all the original defaults that I had previously deleted.  Any reason why this is happening or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

How did you delete the item(via Outlook client or owa)?

If you deleted them in Outlook desktop client, it's suggested to delete in owa, which is closer to server via *open another mailbox>type your shared mailbox>settings>delete the category item*

It should be work now.